# Empty HTTP Get response body when okhttp3 is used

Tags: java, kotlin, okhttp

I'm trying to make GET request to some url - as result status response is 200 but response body is very strange - ***okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@84f1f6e***. I have this result for any url("https://www.bbc.com/russia" is for example). Below is snapshot of my code:

```
val httpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor())
    .addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
    .build()


fun runCheckQualityPeriodic() {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.bbc.com/russia")
        .build()

    val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

    val response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()
    Logger.tag("krv").v("runCheckQualityPeriodic responce is " + response)
    val body = response.body().toString()
    Logger.tag("krv").v("runCheckQualityPeriodic responce body is " + body)
}
```

Below are screenshots from StethoInterceptor:

[image]
Do you have any idea why I receive such result?

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` shows a developer-friendly representation. To get the actual content you need to change

```
response.body().toString()
```

to

```
response.body().string()
```